# Are all preorders implication relations?

Tags: order-theory

This question is for the people who know what consequence relations are. Just to clarify, a consequence relation C on L is a relation from the powerset of L, to L, that satisfies certain properties. We can define the associated implication relation on L to L as a I b iff C({a},b). A general implication on L can be defined as the implication relation for some consequence relation on L. Every implication relation is a preorder. Are all preorders on L implication relations, for all L?

Comment: The order "is a sentence of length less than or equal to" cannot come from logical implication, since some relations are not in the order, but for any $X$ and $Y$, a long enough conjunction $X \wedge X \wedge X \dots$ is later in the order than any $Y$, so in any $L$ where $X \wedge X$ entails $X$, every pair is related.  That's assuming "consequence relation" is set up to axiomatize derivability in formal systems of logic, but I have never seen the definition (or even the words *consequence relation* before this question), so who knows whether it answers what you want.